# WordPress site redirection problem for links without trailing /

Tags: wordpress, redirect, slash

We have a situation where a **single database** serves 2 same WordPress sites:

https://example1.com
https://example2.com

Both sites are identical and use one and same database.

The problem - links on example2.com **without the trailing / at the end redirect** to example1.com. For instance:

https://example2.com/about/ - works OK
https://example2.com/about - redirects to https://example1.com/about/ which we do not want

How can this be solved?

I tried removing the trailing / from the Settings -> Permalinks but that did not help.

Does the problem lie in using 1 database for both sites? Maybe WordPress uses site url to build redirection links?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two sites from a single database as the stored data includes single site's domain name.

In options table the siteurl is saved.

So you would need to use two databases.

Comment: I understand. But what if I try to set the siteurl dynamically based on $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']? For instance this code in wp-config.php: 
`$site_name = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
define( 'WP_HOME', $site_name );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', $site_name );` This works on localhost but not on the production server :/